# Get express original url input instead of the regexp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

While using Expressjs, I can define middleware for routes, like this `app.get('/home', fn);`, but it's also possible to do the following:

```
const customRouter = express.Router();
customerRouter.get('/foo', fn);
customerRouter.get('/foo/:id', fn);

app.use('/custom', customRouter);
```

For the `/home` route, I can access `app._router.stack`, iterate through it and I can find the routes I declared by accessing an object on the `stack` and access the property `route`.

For `customRouter`, it almost works the same, I can access the `route` property, but it only gives me `/foo` and `/foo/:id`

Does anyone know how I can get the full url for it?
So a console.log would return `/custom/foo` or `/custom/foo/:id`

Comment: Its correct because of `app.use('/custom', customRouter);` line you are not able to access all routes. if you want you can do `app.use('/', customRouter);`.

Comment: The client is able to access all routes, no problem there. Want I'm trying to get is a list of routes defined and I need it to support those customRouters

Comment: I think this is not possible. I tried something similar and had not find the solution. The simplest method is to add custom middleware to add `'/custom'` to the req object